# Include html pages with angular JS and just actualize them when refreshing

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm developing an application using angular JS . I have a menu and when I click on one of the options it becomes active (changes color ) and I include a different html page. for example :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">

                    <li > 
                      <a href="#" ng-click="subPage.url='home.html'" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i> Home </a>
                    </li>  
                    <li > 
                      <a href="#" ng-click="subPage.url='profil.html'" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i> Profil</a>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

........

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">  
          <!-- Page Heading -->    
        <div ng-include="subPage.url"></div>

 </div>
</div>
```

that works fine . but when I refresh the page I always  get the welcome page with no page included . I tried to initialize the subPage.url :

```
<div  ng-init="subPage.url = 'home.html'">
```

but this way when I refresh I always get the home.html included . 
How to do so that when I refresh I keep having the same page included and refresh it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh the page, the application starts from scratch. All you've stored in memory (i.e. the subPage url) is lost.

You should use a router (ngRoute or ui-router). Clicking on a menu option should change the URL in addition to changing the view. That way, refreshing the page would start the application again, but the router would still see that the URL is the one of a sub page, and would automatically route to that sub page.

Comment: isn't that a problem ? because I want to keep the same top-nav and side-nav and just change a part of the page note the whole one

Comment: That's what a router does.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a $routeProvider and set your default route ('/') to home.html.
Look here for more info: https://thinkster.io/egghead/routeprovider-api

Comment: Ok , thank you I set my routeProvider and it works , but when I refresh , the option is no more active (colored) and for example I have to call a function (getusers() for example) but IT DOESN'T work until I click a new time on the option . I tried to use ng-init or onload  but it doen't work .